# Erro ao imprimir uma simples variável

Tags: java, java-8

Não estou conseguindo imprimir um código ultra simples em Java. Acusa o seguinte erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field dou at                          Excript_variaveis.main(Excript_variaveis.java:10)

O código:

```
public class Variaveis {

    int inteiro = 10;
    //float flo = 5.9;
    double dou = 3.8;
    String texto = "Oi";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(dou);
    }
    }
```

Obrigada!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As variáveis pertencem ao objeto Variaveis, então você precisa criar uma instância dele para acessar as variáveis na instância OU alterar as variáveis para `static`:

> Opção 1: Criação da instância

```
public class Variaveis {

    int inteiro = 10;
    //float flo = 5.9;
    double dou = 3.8;
    String texto = "Oi";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Variaveis().dou);
    }
}
```

> Opção 2: Variáveis estáticas

```
public class Variaveis {

    static int inteiro = 10;
    //float flo = 5.9;
    static double dou = 3.8;
    static String texto = "Oi";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(dou);
    }
}
```

Comment: Por um momento de distração, não tinha observado a questão do contexto estático. +1